# Calculating RTT through Python

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming

I am interested in calculating the round-trip time of the connection between a pi and my pc (connected through LAN) and I calculated it by sending a timestamp and then subtracting the received timestamp from the current time. The relevant parts of the code are -

**In server -**

```
send_time = time.time() 
conn.sendto(str(send_time),addr_list[0])

while 1:
    data = conn.recv(1024) 
    d = data.decoode('utf-8')
    if not data : break
    print(float(data) - time.time())
```

**In Client**

```
while 1:
    data = s.recv(1024)
    print("data received")
    s.send(data)
    break
```

I have two things to ask:

1. Why do I get a different result every time I run it? What values should I expect?
2. What should be the value of the chunk in which I should receive the data (here it is 1024)?

Thank you.